# what should i use instead of "slc arc" in strongloop example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

Trying to start strongloop as it prescribed on http://strongloop.com/

```
slc arc
"arc" is not an slc command. See `slc --help` for more information.
```

how should i do it now?

Comment: What OS are you on? Did you `npm install -g strongloop`?

Comment: pm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/babaca/.npm/strongloop/2.10.3/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.1.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "strongloop"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
... mac os x

Comment: Looks like a permission problem. Did you try `sudo`? Or `chown` on `/usr/local`?

Comment: yeap! that was my soooo bad... thanks for your help!